# Unable to open my source code a second time with `python -i`

Tags: python

When I first start bash I can open my code like so:

```
$ python -i index.py
```

That file is open, but when I try again this happens:

```
>>> python -i index.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python -i index.py
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If I close bash and start again it works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're trying to run Python but you're already in Python, on the interactive prompt. Exit first, with `exit()`, or don't run the script interactively (leave the `-i` out)

Answer (score 2):

You can't run terminal commands from the Python REPL.

You can tell you're in the REPL when you see `>>>` as opposed to `$`. This means you can run Python code there, but not shell/terminal commands (like the `python` command).

To exit the REPL, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> or type `exit()` and press enter. This will bring you back to the regular terminal.

---

In addition, I'd recommend running just `python index.py` rather than `python -i index.py` in most cases.

The added `-i` means that you'd like to stay in the REPL to inspect the results after running the `index.py` file. It allows you to continue running additional Python code after the `index.py` file has finished its execution.

Comment: Thanks bro, I get it only changing the python -i index.py for python index.py
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It looks by the three >>> that you are in the python console not in bash itself. If you type exit() you should get back to bash, and then you can try the code again.